# Javascript program to calculate the area of a triangle using all formulas

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, prompt

i am trying to create a program to calculate area of a triangle using either of the formulas below

1. knowing base and height
2. Hebron"s formula
3. Knowing two sides and an included angle

I am to use onclick button for different functions(formulas) using prompt to input users data but the button are not triggering the prompt function

```js
var baseValue = Number(prompt("Enter the base of the triangle: "));
 var heightValue = Number(prompt("Enter the height of the triangle: "));

function formula1(basevalue, heightValue) {
// calculate the area 
var areaValue1 = (baseValue * heightValue) / 2;
return("the area of the triangle is" + areaValue1);

}

var side1 = parseInt(prompt("Enter side1: "));
var side2 = parseInt(prompt("Enter side2: "));
var side3 = parseInt(prompt("Enter side3: "));
 
function formula2(){

//calculate the semi-parameter
 var s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;
//calculate the area
var areaValue2 = Math.sqrt(s * (s - side1) * (s - side2) * (s - side3));
alert("The area of the triangle is " ${areaValue2});

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title> Area of a triangle</title>
  <h1>Formulas to calculate the area of a triangle</h1>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="bgnBtn" onclick="formula1()">Knowing Base and Height<br><br>
    <button id="bgnBtn" onclick="formula2()">Heron's Formula</button><br><br>
  <button id="bgnBtn" onclick="formula3()">Knowing two sides & an angle</button><br><br>

  <script type="text/javascript" scr="Calculator.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `${areaValue2}` is not valid outside a template literal.

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error for that?

Comment: `${areaValue2}` should be `+ areaValue2`

Comment: thanks I thought I had corrected it, but I still can't trigger the prompt method on clicking either of the buttons created

Comment: You're setting the variables with `prompt()` when the page loads, not in the functions that you call from the buttons.

Comment: Move those assignments inside the relevant functions.

Comment: prompt returns a string

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps You.

```js
function formula1() {
  var base = parseInt(prompt("Please enter Base In Units"));
  var height = parseInt(prompt("Please enter Height In Units"));

  let area = base * height / 2;


  console.log(area + ' Sq. Units');
  document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = ('Area:' + area + ' Sq. Units');
}

function formula2() {
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Please enter Side 'I' In Units"));
  var b = parseInt(prompt("Please enter Side 'II' In Units"));
  var c = parseInt(prompt("Please enter Side 'III' In Units"));

  let s = (a + b + c) / 2;

  let product = s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c);
  if (s <= a || s <= b || s <= c) {

    console.log(a, b, c, s);
    console.log('invalid Inputs');
    return;
  }
  let area = Math.sqrt(product).toFixed(3);

  console.log(area + ' Sq. Units');
  document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = ('Area: ' + area + ' Sq. Units');

}

function formula3() {
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Please enter Side 'I' In Units"));
  var b = parseInt(prompt("Please enter Side 'II' In Units"));
  var c = parseInt(prompt("angle made by given lines In deg:"));

  c = c * Math.PI / 180;


  let z = Math.sin(c);
  let area = (0.5 * a * b * z).toFixed(3);

  console.log(area + ' Sq. Units');
  document.getElementById('area').innerHTML = ('Area: ' + area + ' Sq. Units');
}
```

```html
<button id="bgnBtn" onclick="formula1()">Knowing Base and Height</button><br><br>
<button id="bgnBtn" onclick="formula2()">Heron's Formula</button><br><br>
<button id="bgnBtn" onclick="formula3()">Knowing two sides & an angle</button><br><br>

<h3 id='area'></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems, like a few of the comments say, the way you concatenate a string is either by `"hello " + variable` or `` `hello ${variable}` `` but in order to use the ${} method you have to have it inside a string declared with ``` `` ``` instead of `""` or `''`

The next problem is you want to declare the variables inside the function, rather than outside because it is a prompt. For example:

```js
function greetUser() {
    var input = prompt("Whats your name?");
    alert("Hello " + input);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="greetUser()"> Greeting </button>
```

The above works, yet the below doesn't

```js
var input = prompt("Whats your name?");
function greetUser() {
    alert("Hello " + input);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="greetUser()"> Greeting </button>
```

The last one asks for your name at first, but when you click the button it doesn't ask you again, meaning you would have to reload the page to enter a new input.

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! It seems that your post does not answer the question. Could you please edit your answer to be more specific to the question that has been asked?

Comment: @TimWißmann, I'm not sure how it doesn't answer the question... The user asked: "I am to use onclick button for different functions(formulas) using prompt to input users data but the button are not triggering the prompt function". I told them why it wasn't triggering the prompt function. Am I supposed to re-write their code for them?

Comment: Yeah thats true, but it might be more convenient and more understanding for the questioner if some additional  connection to the original question is given. Currently, it is just providing a generic code example. This is why I thought it is more beneficial to improve the answer a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function AreaT() {
    let a = parseInt(document
        .getElementById("a").value);

    let b = parseInt(document
        .getElementById("b").value);

    let c = parseInt(document
        .getElementById("c").value);

    console.log(typeof(a));
    let s = (a + b + c) / 2;

    let area = Math.sqrt(s * ((s - a) 
            * (s - b) * (s - c)));
    console.log(area)
    document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = ( area + '\n'+ 'is the area of trianlge.' );
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Solve Area of Triangle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <h1>AREA OF TRIANGLE KNOWING THREE SIDES</h1>
        <hr />
        <h2>Enter a number in the box .</h2>
        <hr />
        <br><br>
        <button onclick = "AreaT();">Area of Triangle</button>
        <br><br>
        <label for="a">
            Enter Number: 
        </label>
          
        <input type="number" id="a" 
            placeholder="Input Value">
        <br><br>
      
        <label for="b">
            Enter Number: 
        </label>
          
        <input type="number" id="b" 
            placeholder="Input Value">
        <br><br>
      
        <label for="c">
            Enter Number: 
        </label>
          
        <input type="number" id="c" 
            placeholder="Input Value">
        <br><br>
    <p>
        <b><span id="display"></span></b>
    </p>
    </center>
    
    <Script type="text/javascript" src="Function.js"></Script>
</body>
</html>
```